# Postman Collection Runner - read ECONNRESET

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

i'm trying to run a web-service test Using CSV data files in the Postman Collection Runner . When i parameterize and give more than one value , for the 2nd run am getting the following error in the postman console

Postman Collection Runner has two  POST services , first service has email field and 2nd service has phone number .

Service 1 :- POST

```
http://service1/rs/register
{
    "email": "{{email}}",
    "username": "testuser_{{$timestamp}}",
    "newPassword": "Online@1",
    "postalZip": "K2K3N5"
}
```

Service 2 :- POST

```
http://service2/rs/profile/customer
{
    "phone": {{phone}},
    "postalZip": "K2K3N5"
}
```

Service 3 :- PUT

```
http://service3/rs/profile/link
{
    "jobTitle":"Director",
    "title":"Ms"
}
```

for example my CSV file content is as below

```
Email             Phone
test1@gamil.com   1234567890
test2@gmail.com   1234567891
```

for the 2nd run am getting the below error in the console

[image]

Error: read ECONNRESET
Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers

if i run this one by one i.e if the csv has only 1 value at a time then it works without any problem.

Can anyone help me here ?

thanks
Syam